# Flutter - setState is not updating a particular widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am attempting to update two different texts based on tapping the screen. This works successfully in respect of one of the texts, but unsuccessfully for another. I am referring to the TyperAnimatedTextKit widget and the Text widget just below it. The former does not work, but the latter does.

As the code snippet below shows, when the screen is tapped, there are two widgets which are supposed to change. One is a Text Widget. When the screen is tapped, it updates the String to the value in another class "(quoteBrain.getQuoteAuthor()." This actually works and successfully changes the text on screen. Tapping the screen results in calling the ScreenTapped() method which updates the state and grabs the next String from the quoteBrain class.

**However** I am also using a TyperAnimatedTextKit from the Animated Text Kit package. Although the code uses the same logic as the Text widget (i.e. grabbing the string from another class and calling a function to update it), this never works.

I wondered if anyone might be able to provide some insight.

Many thanks and happy to provide any more details.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'quote_brain.dart';
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';

QuoteBrain quoteBrain = QuoteBrain();

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool buttonVisible = true;

  void ScreenTapped() {
    setState(() {
      quoteBrain.NextQuote();
      buttonVisible = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: AssetImage('images/nightsky.png'),
        ),
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('Screen was tapped');
          ScreenTapped();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 150),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TyperAnimatedTextKit(
                        isRepeatingAnimation: false,
                        text: [quoteBrain.getQuoteText()],
                        textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'QuiteMagical', fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        quoteBrain.getQuoteAuthor(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'QuiteMagical', fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 54),
                      Visibility(
                        visible: buttonVisible,
                        child: FadeAnimatedTextKit(
                          repeatForever: false,
                          text: ["TAP ANYWHERE"],
                          textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**QuoteBrain Class**

```
import 'quote.dart';

class QuoteBrain {
  int quoteIndex = 0;

  List<Quote> _quoteBank = [
    Quote('\"This is an example of a quote. I am making it really long to see how it wraps\"', '\~Person One'),
    Quote('This is a second test of a quote', '\~Person Two')
  ];

  String getQuoteText() {
    return _quoteBank[quoteIndex].quoteText;
  }

  String getQuoteAuthor() {
    return _quoteBank[quoteIndex].quoteAuthor;
  }

  void NextQuote() {
    if (quoteIndex < _quoteBank.length - 1) {
      quoteIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Quote Class**

```
class Quote {
  String quoteText;
  String quoteAuthor;

  Quote(this.quoteText, this.quoteAuthor);
}
```

Comment: please provide QuoteBrain  class

Comment: @TipuSultan Thanks I have added the quotebrain class and the quote class to the post

Comment: @macl64 This has something to do with the animated-text widget. People have faced the same issue earlier and the corresponding issue on github has been closed without a solution. Link to the issue - https://github.com/aagarwal1012/Animated-Text-Kit/issues/27

Comment: @JigarPatel Thanks for that background. I guess for now I will try and find an alternative way of achieving the animated effects I wanted (an animation where one letter appears after the other)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still facing this issue, you need to add a ValueKey to your AnimatedTextKitWidget.

So for the question it should be

```dart
TyperAnimatedTextKit(
                        key: ValueKey(quoteBrain.getQuoteText()),
                        isRepeatingAnimation: false,
                        text: [quoteBrain.getQuoteText()],
                        textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'QuiteMagical', fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                      )
```

Calling setState now should update your widget as intended